# Rails Is there something like polymorphic_url that respects scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have yet to find a solution that doesn't involve something very hacky.

Problem: Our rails application has uses namespaces to override behavior of the parent controllers and models (using STI). In blog nomenclature its sort of like this:

```
blog
  posts

admin
  blog <- blog
    posts <- blog::posts
    orders <- blog::posts
namespace2
  blog <- blog
    posts <- blog::posts
    comments <- blog::posts
    awesome_comments <- blog::posts
```

This is a simpler example, but each namespace overrides validations, behaviors and what STI objects its children are. The parent uses reflection to give the user buttons that correspond to the children it has. This would require using polymorphic_url, however rails has a very funny way of handling nested resources sharing a namespace

It likes this: namespace/blog/:id/namespace/posts,
which I suppose can work... if you want a giant url.

I tried

```
scope :module => :namespace, :name_prefix => :namespace do
  resources :blog do
    resources :post
    resources :comment
  end
end
```

But... polymorphic_path does not seem to get this... it wants:

```
namespace :namespace
  resources :blog do
    namespace :namespace
      resources :comment
      resources :post
    end
  end
end
```

Which not only is not DRY, but seems like I'm doing something wrong.

Is there something like polymorphic_url that respects scope?

Comment: Further research also indicates what seems to be unintuitive behavior: if you have a nested scope resource, the scope adds the as prefix before the parent, not the child. eg. instead of blog_admin_posts you get: admin_blog_posts.